# Is there a way to convert my code into a loop to be more efficient

Tags: c++, loops

I'd like to turn all these `else if` statements into one giant `for` loop so that I don't have to continue to have all these extra statements.  I know it's possible, but every time that I tried to make it work, it would loop through the array and not properly check the conditions.

```
else if ((isdigit(stdID[1]) == false) || (stdID[1] == '0')) {
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 3) {
        std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
        std::cout << "You used all Three Attempts\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
    std::cout << "Incorrect format, please enter a valid Student ID\n";
    continue;
}        
else if ((isdigit(stdID[2]) == false) || (stdID[2] == '0')) {
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 3) {
        std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
        std::cout << "You used all Three Attempts\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
    std::cout << "Incorrect format, please enter a valid Student ID\n";
    continue;
}
else if ((isdigit(stdID[3]) == false) || (stdID[3] == '0')) {
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 3) {
        std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
        std::cout << "You used all Three Attempts\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";;
    std::cout << "Incorrect format, please enter a valid Student ID\n";
    continue;
}
else if ((isdigit(stdID[4]) == false) || (stdID[4] == '0')) {
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 3) {
        std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
        std::cout << "You used all Three Attempts\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
    std::cout << "Incorrect format, please enter a valid Student ID\n";
    continue;
}
else if ((isdigit(stdID[5]) == false) || (stdID[5] == '0')) {
    attempt++;
    if (attempt == 3) {
        std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
        std::cout << "You used all Three Attempts\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
    std::cout << "Incorrect format, please enter a valid Student ID\n";
    continue;
}
else
    break;
```

Comment: This code can be simplified, but if you show the entire function, that would clarify which algorithm this is.

Comment: You should take a cut at writing it yourself and ask about the attempt if you have any questions.

Comment: If the code is *working* (a hard requirement) this is better suited for [the CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Common mistake, you ask for help but show us the code that is working, instead of the code that is not working. Much easier to help when you show the effort you have made, instead of asking everyone here to repeat that effort.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Notice how you always access `stdD[i]` at an increasing index. This index can be extracted into a loop variable.

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    // the if-condition can be simplified
    if (!isdigit(stdID[i]) || stdID[i] == '0') {
        attempt++;
        if (attempt == 3) {
            std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
            std::cout << "You used all Three Attempts\n";
            return 0;
        }
        std::cout << "ID contained a Zero \n";
        std::cout << "Incorrect format, please enter a valid Student ID\n";
        break; // also put other code to handle non-digits/zeros here
    }
}
```